# Show <mat-form-field> depening on <mat-select>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to show a   (another ) depending of another . I tried to set *ngIf to check if the  in the first field is ' ', but it doesnt work. What is the proper way to archieve it?

```
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Manufacterer" [(ngModel)]="manufactererValue" name="manufacterer">
      <mat-option> </mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server.manufacterer">
        {{server.manufacterer}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="manufactererValue != ' '">
    <mat-select placeholder="Model" [(ngModel)]="modelValue" name="model">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server.manufacterer">
        {{server.model}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly use qualifiers like manufactererValue  == '' or manufactererValue  != ''. Like in JavaScript, an empty string will be evaluated as false.

Try

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!manufactererValue">
```